# In the AWS CLI how do I treat a special character as a string?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to run an AWS CLI command for a resource with a ! in its name. I'm doing this from CentOS Docker instance running on my local device a MAC and if I run

```bash
echo "$SHELL"
```

it says it is using bash

Using echo 'test!'  works for returning the value
but testing in my CLI command it does not work

```
aws autoscaling put-scheduled-update-group-action --auto-scaling-group-name temp_asg --scheduled-action-name 'test!' --start-time 2020-12-06T12:00:00Z --min-size 0 --max-size 1 --desired-capacity 0 --region eu-west-1 --output json
```

returns
bash: !`: event not found

my AWS CLI version in the docker instance I'm running it from is
aws-cli/1.16.251

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I put it in a script it sees it as a string and it's only an issue running directly from the terminal/command prompt but not an issue when running from a script with the header/shabang
#!/bin/bash
My final goal for this is for it to be part of a script so this has resolved my issue.

Im still not 100% on the issue when directly in the terminal and don't know if it's specific to the shell I'm using?